# PHP submit to txt file

Tags: php

I have a subscribe option on my page. All I want is for users to be able to subscribe via email and have their emails save to a `.txt` file.

Here is my HTML form code:

```
<form action="contacts.php" method="post">
 E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Subscribe to our page for the latest News & Updates">
 <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

I just need to know the script to write in the `contacts.php` file to save the emails.

I'm using XAMPP as a local server.

Comment: If this really your HTML code, it will never work.  Edit your question and format the HTML as code.

Comment: No need to be rude I'm reaching out for help from my fellow programmers I just said in my question it wouldnt let me post the html open close tags ...I know how to make a form correctly thank u

Comment: Please see this link regarding formatting code blocks, but basically, it is either hitting the `{ }` button, using back-tics or putting 4 spaces in front of all code lines.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for details. I submitted an edit of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Form

```
<form action="contacts.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Subscribe to our page for the latest News & Updates" />
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Use this code in your **contacts.php**

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 file_put_contents('emails.txt', $email . PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: You need to correct you html code to work it, its only server side code

Comment: That's exactly how I have it... I have it saved in xampp ..do I need a seperate txt file for the emails or does it go in php...I'm confused on this...